# Query last event each person attended

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table called CampRegistration with the following structure:

```
[EID] INT, [CampName] VARCHAR(100), [StartDt] DATETIME
```

EID is the identifier of the person who attended the camp. I wish to select the last camp each person in the CampRegistration table has attended prior to a given date.

Here was my first attempt:

```
@DECLARE @currentCampDt DATETIME = '2012-8-4';
SELECT [EID], [CampName], MAX([StartDt]) [StartDt]
FROM [CampRegistration]
WHERE [StartDt] < @currentCampDt 
GROUP BY [EID],[CampName]
order by [EID]
```

The problem here is that if someone has attended multiple camps w/ different names I'll get multiple results for that person (the last attended of each camp name). I only wish to get a single record back for each person, the last camp of any name they attended. I do ultimately need to get those three pieces of info for each record (EID, CampName, and the camp's StartDt) so I'm not sure if I really can remove CampName from the `Group By`.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to implement this type of query result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `EID` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some criteria.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH CampEvents AS
(
   SELECT 
       EID, CampName, StartDt,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY StartDt DESC)
   FROM 
       dbo.CampRegistration
)
SELECT 
   EID, CampName, StartDt
FROM 
   CampEvents
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `EID`) - ordered by the descending `StartDt` - so the newest, most recent event has `RowNum = 1`.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Comment: That's clever. I think it will work for me, Thank you. May I ask is the initial ; there to just make sure any previous statement was completed before starting the CTE?

Comment: @user1911175: yes, exactly - the CTE itself doesn't require a leading `;` - but the preceeding command must have been terminated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be fast, but will do it:

```
@DECLARE @currentCampDt DATETIME = '2012-8-4';

SELECT o.[EID], o.[CampName], o.[StartDt]
FROM [CampRegistration] o
WHERE o.[StartDt] = ( 
                      SELECT MAX(i.[StartDt]) 
                      FROM [CampRegistration] i WHERE i.[StartDt] < @currentCampDt
                      AND
                      i.[EID] = o.[EID]
                    )
order by o.[EID]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
WITH LastCampsAttended
As
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY StartDt DESC) AS rownum
  FROM CampRegistration
  WHERE [StartDt] < @currentCampDt 
)
SELECT 
  EID,
  CampName,
  StartDt
FROM LastCampsAttended
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1a3f/2)

**Or:**

```
SELECT
  camps.*
FROM CampRegistration camps
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT EID, MAX(StartDt) LatestDate
  FROM CampRegistration
  GROUP BY EID
) LatestCamps  ON camps.EID = LatestCamps.EID
              AND camps.StartDt = LatestCamps.LatestDate
WHERE camps.StartDt < @currentCampDt ;
```

### [Updated SQL fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1a3f/3)

Comment: Two where clauses in a single select. Typo?